# jQuery Search for Text in a Variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that contains some text, some html, basically can be a string. I need to search the variable for a specific string to process that variable differently if it is contained. Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do, does not work obviously :)

```
$.each(data.results,
   function(i, results) {
   var text = this.text                   
   var pattern = new RegExp("^[SEARCHTERM]$");
    if(pattern.test( text ) )
    alert(text);  //was hoping this would alert the SEARCHTERM if found...
```

Comment: what it say when you do a `alert(this.text)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `.indexOf()` instead to perform the search.

If the string is not found, it returns `-1`. If it is found, it returns the *first zero-based index* where it was located.

```
var text = this.text;
var term = "SEARCHTERM";

if( text.indexOf( term ) != -1 )
    alert(term);
```

If you were hoping for an exact match, which your use of `^` and `$` seems to imply, you could just do an `===` comparison.

```
var text = this.text;
var term = "SEARCHTERM";

if( text === term )
    alert(term);
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, you want an exact match, but `===` isn't working, while `indexOf()` is. This is sometimes the case if there's some whitespace that needs to be trimmed.

Try trimming the whitespace using [jQuery's `jQuery.trim()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/).

```
var text = $.trim( this.text );
var term = "SEARCHTERM";

if( text === term )
    alert(term);
```

If this doesn't work, I'd recommend logging `this.text` to the console to see if it is the value you expect.

Comment: Thanks, so I am looking for an exact match to the search term, but the === comparison did not seem to work.  Using indexOf, however, does. Why would that be?

Comment: @thatryan: It would depend on the value of `this.text`. Without knowing what `data.results` holds, I can't say for sure, but I'd guess that perhaps there's some whitespace that needs to be trimmed. The `indexOf()` will locate any partial match in the string, so it may give false positives at times, while `===` will fail if there's any difference, including whitespace. I updated my answer.

Comment: I did Patrick, thanks. Sorry I thought I had checked it as answered! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a regular expression to search for a substring, you can find the match like this:

```
var match = text.match(pattern);
if(match) {
    alert(match[0]);
}
```

See the documentation for [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for more information.

Note that if you are trying to search for the string `"[SEARCHTERM]"` (a search term containing brackets), your search method will not work because the brackets have a special meaning within regular expressions. Instead, use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var index = text.indexOf("[SEARCHTERM]");
if(index != -1) {
    alert("Search term found");
}
```

However, if you are just trying to find an exact match (nothing else but the search term is in the string you are checking), you should just compare the strings:

```
if(text == "[SEARCHTERM]") {
    alert("Search term found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does "does not work" mean here?

Be aware that you should use braces (`{}`) with `if` statements. Some browsers will allow you to miss them out but you should include them to be correct and to support everything.

Comment: Oh, and you're missing a semi-colon on the line in which you initialise the variable `test`.

Comment: *"Some browsers will allow you..."* Excluding them is actually allowed by the language specification, but certainly good practice to include them.

Comment: @patrick dw: Ah, oops! Thanks for that. I admit I'd always just assumed; still, widespread browsers like IE6 will not be happy with it IME, so best to keep them in.