# How to check if string is present in variable in jquery

Tags: javascript

I have the variable like

`var myVar = "The man is running"`

`pattern = "run"`

I want to check via jquery that if it conatins words "run"

Like

```
if($(myVar).(:contains(pattern)))
return true
```

Is this possible

Comment: I feel I should recommend that you review the [difference between JavaScript and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript). Here you can read up on [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/About_JavaScript#What_is_JavaScript.3F). Here you can read up on [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Comment: Check this:
@john110016
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581625/jquery-search-for-text-in-a-variable

is exactly like your questions

Answer (score 24, accepted):

RegExp option...just because..RegExp.

```
var pattern = /run/;

//returns true or false...
var exists = pattern.test(myVar);

if (exists) {
  //true statement, do whatever
} else {
  //false statement..do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You would use the Javascript method `.indexOf()` to do this. If you're trying to test whether the text of a DOM element contains the pattern, you would use this:

```
if($(myVar).text().indexOf(pattern) != -1)
    return true;
```

If the variable `myVar` isn't a selector string, you shouldn't wrap it in the jQuery function, though. Instead, you would use this:

```
if(myVar.indexOf(pattern) != -1)
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need jQuery for this. Just check for the index of the string.

`if (myVar.indexOf(pattern) !== -1) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Regex?

```
var hasRun = /run/i.test(myVar) // case insensitive
```

Comment: A regex has unnecessary overhead for such a simple operation, though.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably slower than `indexOf` but an option nonetheless and more readable, at least IMO.